# What effect do fortresses have on the world in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In dwarf fortress, what effects do fortresses have on the overall world? Can you play a military outpost defending from invading armies or play a large farming complex supplying the surrounding area with food through trade?

Overall can your fortress have a lasting effect on the world? (limited to of course what a small/medium fortress could do)

Comment: "Large" farming complex? I've got one 10x10 indoor room and about the same outdoors area dedicated to farm plots, another 10x10 room for food preparation workshops and kitchens, and they generate enough food to feed my entire population ten times over and still have more than enough left to buy entire caravans with...

Comment: I plan to use plump helmet barrels as catapult ammo rather then rocks, so I'll need a fair bit of extra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point in time, they don't much to affect the world map, though they will probably be expanded to do some things in the 2013 release based on some of Toady One's dev notes.

Most things don't apply to history if you do them in the fort. For example, if someone declares war on your fort they do not enter a state of war with your civilization

Important people and megabeasts you destroy are removed from the world map, so killing them will help your civilization by preventing those attackers from destroying other areas.

I believe they also generate people once retired.

Economic effects don't exist yet, that may or may not appear in DF2013.